# regex capturing groups and subcapturing groups

Tags: regex

here is my teststring:

> 1,feE,(1,234,gtE),w2,(),$

My desired output is:

```
1
feE
(1,234,gtE)
w2

$
```

I'm programming with PHP and not with .NET.
The whole string is much more complicated but this part I can't solve for my own.

My idea was: Find a value or a tuple several times follwed with a comma or a value and a tupel.

```
(?|(([^(),]+),|((\([^()]\)+))))
```

But I don't find the solution.
Can some help me please?

Comment: `(\((?:[^(),\s]+\s*,\s*)*[^(),\s]+\)|[^(),]+)`?

Comment: Here's how I would do it https://regex101.com/r/8Fcx6K/1

Answer (score 0):

What disturbs me is the 5th match, being empty whereas 3rd one includes parenthesis.

Anyway, given your example, using the following it should be ok:

```
(?=\()(?:\([^)]+\)|)|[^,()]+
                   ^
    Here, as alternative is nothing, empty pair of parenthesis retrieves an empty match
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/QITiIy/1).

Considering the real match wanted (i.e. parenthesis should actually match even when empty), you could modify as follows :

```
(?:\([^)]*\))|[^,()]+
```

Lookahead has been removed to skip identifying a leading parenthesis, directly matching it instead. Also removed the in between alternation for an empty match as it' not needed anymore.

Updated [demo](https://regex101.com/r/QITiIy/2).

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. You are right. The 5th element should be resulted as (). What do I have to change for that?

Comment: Ok, I still have problems embedding it in my regex:                                             `^(?:#)([0-9]+)(?:[ ]*=[ ]*)(ifc[a-z0-9]+)\(    (.*)     \);`  In the last (.*) should be the regex by you. A whole teststring would be: `#114= IFCBUILDING('Pi',#41,(#32,AaZ,432,§ER),(),.ELEMENT.);` The output goes like: 114, IFCBUILDING, 'Pi, ...

Comment: It's normal, including all those parameters will go to a whole match. If you use .NET regexes, you'll then be able to work with successively captured groups (see [Group.Captures Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures(v=vs.110).aspx)). Else you could use 2 regexes (your comment one to get the full match, leading number and IFCwhatever, the answer one to retrieve individual parameters).

Comment: Thanks for helping me to understand regex. I do 2 step regex then.